# Questions about the syntax of trigger in Derby

Tags: sql, derby, database-trigger

I am using Netbeans 8 and I tried to add a trigger into my database.

Firstly, I right clicked on the procedures and chose execute command.

My command is as followed.

```
DELIMITER @@

CREATE TRIGGER INSERTFRIENDSHIP

AFTER INSERT ON FRIENDSHIP

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

IF (NEW.STUDENTID1 > NEW.STUDENTID2) 

DECLARE MID INT;

SET MID = NEW.STUDENTID2;

SET NEW.STUDENTID2 = NEW.STUDENTID1;

SET NEW.STUDENTID1 = MID;

END IF ;

END; @@

DELIMITER ;
```

I tried to insert the lighter data into the left side column.

But the error appeared

```
[Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42X01] Syntax error: Encountered "BEGIN" at line 7, column 1.
```

Line 9, column 1

Does anyone know the actual trigger syntax of the Derby database?

And how can I fix it?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Please tag with the database that you are using.  Netbeans supports multiple databases.

Comment: How can I know which database I'm using?

Comment: The database connected is Java DB, jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/FIT5046AssignmentDB [jwan519 on JWAN519]

Comment: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/ref/rrefsqlj43125.html